# Query multiple totals at once in MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have a a table in my DB that has multiple columns with numbers I would like to query all the rows in 1 query with separate totals for all rows in each column in my db.

like so

```
$sql = '
SELECT sum(TOTAL1) 
     , sum(TOTAL2)
     , sum(TOTAL3)
     , sum(TOTAL4) 
  FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '.$ID.'';
```

it works when I do it with a single column query like this.

```
$sql = 'SELECT sum(TOTAL1) FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '.$ID.'';
```

but I can't seem to get it to work for multiples in 1 query does anyone know of a more proper way of doing this instead of in separate queries?

Comment: Use aliases. `SELECT sum(TOTAL1) as total1, sum(TOTAL2) as total2` etc. maybe even something like `SELECT sum(TOTAL1 + TOTAL2 + TOTAL3)`

Comment: Using the aliases worked fine for me 8-) I have used these before don't know why I didn't try that. Thank You Fred.

Comment: Note that any time you have enumerated columns (x1,x2,x3,etc) it's likely that there's something very wrong with your design

Comment: I have many numbers that have been minimized into single rows in a table seems to work pretty good but I am interested in why you would say that Strawberry and I'm wondering what direction you would take in my situation.

Comment: Just to test `SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) as total FROM table` with a `while` loop worked beautifully. *The proof is in the pudding* ;-)

Comment: Because a database table is NOT a spreadsheet!!

Comment: @Strawberry *"Because a database table is NOT a spreadsheet!!"* - So why did they come up with the `SUM()` aggregate function? May as well scrap that idea.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: The guy wants to do mathematical equations on the DB side, nothing wrong with that. He's certainly not going to achieve it with a simple select, then using PHP to count. That would require additional resources. @Strawberry

Comment: the way I am doing it does seem to work fine and pretty fast too.

Comment: Did you want the question closed and marked as solved? Let me know if you want me to put in an answer. The choice is yours @Nato

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've not suggested otherwise.

Comment: I tried it and it does not give me each count the way I need it I have each query running separately like the single one in my example above. It's works fine with them all separate but when I change them to a single query even with the alias it doesn't count the total for each column :/

Comment: @Nato Probably because of the way you're doing it. I've posted an answer below for you to look at, and is easier to demonstrate in a graphical way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = 'SELECT (sum(TOTAL1)+sum(TOTAL2)+sum(TOTAL3)+sum(TOTAL4)) AS FINALTOTAL FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '.$ID.'';
```

Comment: I need a total count from each column of every row.

Answer (score 0):

Use aliases.

*Sidenote:* Add your `WHERE` clause to the *tested* examples I've given below.

```
SELECT sum(TOTAL1) as total1, sum(TOTAL2) as total2
```

which if you want to use seperate aliases, is handy if you wish to echo them as different entities.

For example:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(col1) as total1, 
        SUM(col2) as total2, 
        SUM(col3) as total3 FROM table ");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    echo $row['total1']; // echo'd 125

    echo "<br>";

    echo $row['total2']; // echo'd 225

    echo "<br>";

    echo $row['total3']; // echo'd 2000

}
```

Sidenote: My three columns contained the following:

- col1 in 2 rows 25, 100
- col2 in 2 rows 25, 200
- col3 in 2 rows 1000, 1000

To echo the total of all rows and for example: (and inside the `while` loop)

```
$total = $row['total1'] + $row['total2'] + $row['total3'];

echo $total;
```

Or in one go and as one alias and one row echo'd:

```
SELECT sum(TOTAL1 + TOTAL2 + TOTAL3) as total FROM table
```

I.e.:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(col1 + col2 + col3) as total FROM table ");

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    echo $row['total'];

}
```

Comment: I tried this, it still has problems seems to work except all rows beyond the second are all showing me the same results as the second sum() weird and glitchy

Comment: @Nato You'll need to dig further into your rows then. I wouldn't have posted my answer; not without testing it myself. Check to see what your column types are, if data are integers and/or contains commas/dots. I.e.: `5,000` or `5.000` if you meant `5000` (five thousand).

Comment: they are all whole numbers, and my columns are integers, the problem is it is duplicating the number across the columns. and I need the total for each column.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: DATA TYPE must be same for all fields which you want to SUM 
By following query you can have SUM(field1)+SUM(field2)+ SUM(field3) .....n in 1 single field 
I used this query for just 2 fields and both are integers

See this is my table definition

```
create table `siso_area_operativa` (
    `id_area_operativa` int ,
    `area_operativa` varchar (8),
    `responsable` int 
);
```

and this is query which you want

```
SELECT SUM(a.field1)  FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
    SUM(id_area_operativa) field1
    FROM 
    siso_area_operativa
    UNION ALL
     SELECT SUM(responsable) field1
     FROM 
    siso_area_operativa ) AS a
```

Result of this is 
SUM(id_area_operativa) + SUM(responsable) in single field

ENJOY !!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: This is interesting, I will give this a try this afternoon.

Comment: what this did was give me a total count for all the columns I need a count for each individually NOTE: I am also using a group by function while this is all happening.

Comment: @Nato can you past me your final query which you want to use ?

Comment: I did not find a solution for this issue as of yet, I am running multiple query's with individual sum() functions applied to each. I wish someone could help me find a way around this issue.

Comment: @Nato I am not getting what you exactly want?

1. you want all total in one field or you want 
2. separate sum fields in each field by id?

Comment: please past me your table structure and output exactly you want